# extract value from file that contain an array

Tags: php

I have an array that when I print_r, it gives me this:

```
  stdClass Object ( [Title] => Captain Phillips [Year] => 2013 [Rated] => PG-13     [Released] => 11 Oct 2013 [Runtime] => 134 min )
```

Here is my code:

```
<h2>Demarrage script torrent 1</h2> 
<?php
require_once 'rss_php.php';
$rss = new rss_php;
$rss->load('http://rss.imdb.com/list/XGTJ_c0RTbQ');
$arr = $rss->getRSS();
echo $arr[rss][channel]{'title'};
echo "<br>";
foreach ($arr[rss][channel] as $val1) {
    $title = $val1['title'];
    if (strlen($title) > 3) {
        $date = split('[()]', $title);
        $title = substr($title, 0, -7);
        if (stripos($date[1], "series") !== false) {
            continue;
        } else {
            echo $title;
            echo "<br>";
            $poslink = stripos($val1['link'], "/tt");
            $poslink = $poslink + "1";
            $rest = substr($val1['link'], $poslink, -1);
            $urlimg = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=" . $rest; 
            $arrimg = (json_decode(file_get_contents($urlimg)));
            print_r ($arrimg);
            echo"<br>";
            ?>
            <form action="" method="POST">
               <input type="hidden" name="linktube[]" id="linktube" value="<?php echo $title ?>" />
               <input type="hidden" name="linktube[]" id="linktube" value="<?php echo $date[1] ?>" />
               <input type="submit" value="Trailler" />
            </form>
            <?php
         }
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['linktube'])) {
    $arr1 = $_POST['linktube']; 
    $movieName = str_replace(' ', '+', $arr1[0]);
    $movieYear = $arr1[1];
    $page = file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='.$movieName.'+'.$movieYear.'+trailer&aq=1&hl=en');
    if ($page) {
        if (preg_match('~<a .*?href="/watch\?v=(.*?)".*?</div>~s', $page, $matches))
              $youtubelink = "http://www.youtube.com/v/" . $matches[1];
            echo $youtubelink; 
            echo "<script>window.location = '$youtubelink'</script>";
        } else {
            echo "<b>Trailler not found</b>";
        }
}
?>
```

I tried:

```
echo $arrimg[0]['Runtime'];

echo $arrimg['Runtime']
```

Every time I try to print the runtime value, it blocks my code and ends the loop. I don't understand what the problem. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `block my code`

Comment: The loop end up and it does not show the Runetime value

Comment: While cleaning up your code formatting, I noticed that you're missing an opening brace for the **if** statement that begins with `if (preg_match('~<a .*?href="/watch\?v=(.*?)".*?</div>~s', $page, $matches))`, and a closing brace for the **if** statement that begins with `if ($page) {`.